# How to set a latitude and a longitude arraylist in a single latlng arraylist and then display list of latlng coordinates

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, google-maps-markers

I have been working on getting markers drawn from an sqlite database. So far i have gotten so far that the application displays the last marker from the database using a for loop but I am not sure how to display all the locations. My guess is that the applications goes through the for loop of location_latitude and for loop for location_longitude but stores only the last variables. I understand that i am trying to store an arraylist in a variable and then trying to store the variable in a LatLng Arraylist, i don't know how to store all the values from the location_latitude and location_longitude to the LatLng arraylist.

Here is the MapsActivity where im trying to show the locations
MapsActivity.java

```
   private GoogleMap mMap;
   TextView viewResult;
   MyDatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper;
   Double latitude = null;
   Double longitude = null;
   ArrayList<String> location_id, location_title;
   ArrayList<Double> location_latitude, location_longitude;
   ArrayList<LatLng> locations;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
       // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
       SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
               .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
       mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


       //Initialize variables
       myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(MapsActivity.this);
       location_id = new ArrayList<>();
       location_title = new ArrayList<>();
       location_latitude = new ArrayList<>();
       location_longitude = new ArrayList<>();
       locations = new ArrayList<>();

       storeDataInArrays();

       //Set arraylist containing latitude into a variable
       for (int i = 0; i < location_latitude.size(); i++) {

           latitude = (Double.valueOf(location_latitude.get(i)));
       }

       //Set arraylist containing longitude into a variable
       for (int i = 0; i < location_longitude.size(); i++) {

           longitude = (Double.valueOf(location_longitude.get(i)));
       }
       //add latitude and longitude variables into locations arraylist
       locations.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
   }

   @Override
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       mMap = googleMap;

       // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
       LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


       //Display markers from locations arraylist
       for(LatLng location : locations){
           mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(location)
           .title("marker"));
       }
   }

   //Get data from database and store in arrays
   void storeDataInArrays() {
       Cursor cursor = myDatabaseHelper.readAllData();
       if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
           while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
               location_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
               location_title.add(cursor.getString(1));
               location_latitude.add(cursor.getDouble(2));
               location_longitude.add(cursor.getDouble(3));

           }

       }

   }

}
```

Here is the database helper's read all data method

```
 //readalldata method 
    public Cursor readAllData() {
        String query1 = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(sqLiteDatabase != null) {
            cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query1,null);
        }
        return cursor;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach for the code you posted is to modify the `storeDataInArrays` method to populate the `locations` list directly:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    location_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
    location_title.add(cursor.getString(1));

    locations.add(new LatLng(cursor.getDouble(2),cursor.getDouble(3)));

}
```

And then eliminate the code in `onCreate` after `storeDataInArrays`:

```
    // .. snippet from onCreate
    storeDataInArrays();

    // remove code loops etc.
}
```

Also, although it's not a problem in your code, its worth noting that the `onMapReady` is asynchronous (but called on the UI thread) so it may be clearer to call `storeDataInArrays` before calling `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);`.  Since the `onMapReady` depends on the locations already being populated.  (Technically it would always be called after since it would be on the same looper.)

---

At some point you may realize you want all of the location information encapsulated together (id, title, lat,lng) and one way to do this is to make a private class in your activity class and use that is as the list type as in :

```
private static class MyLatLngData {
   private String id;
   private String title;
   private LatLng latlng;
   public MyLatLngData(String id, String title, double lat, double lng) {
       this.id = id;
       this.title = title;
       this.latlng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
   }
   // add getters and setters or make fields public....e.g.
   public LatLng getLatLng() { return latlng; }
   public void setLatLng(LatLng latlng) { this.latlng = latlng; }
   public String getTitle() { return title; }
  // add others...
```

}

And your `storeDataInArrays` would become:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // remove all previous list adds.
    locations.add(new MyLatLngData(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getDouble(2), cursor.getDouble(3));

}
```

And the `locations` definition would look like:

```
ArrayList<MyLatLngData> locations;
```

And the marker loop would become:

```
//Display markers from locations arraylist
for(MyLatLngData location : locations){
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(location.getLatLng())
    .title("marker"));  // here you could use location.getTitle()
}
```

Comment: That is amazing, thank you very much! Very clear and informative. I spent quite a while working it to the point i had it done that far but your contribution really helped a lot.